# How to detect "browser plug-in" library dependency before execution

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

As we know, there are two methods of library loading.

1) Static libraries (.a): Library of object code which is linked with, and becomes part of the application. 
2) Dynamically linked shared object libraries (.so), which will link at execution of application and it can be used in two ways.

```
a) Dynamically linked at run time but statically aware. 
b) Dynamically loaded/unloaded and linked during execution (i.e. browser plug-in) using the dynamic linking loader system functions.
```

After compilation, we can check the library dependency of type 'a' as below

objdump -x  usr/bin/flashcp

.....

Dynamic Section:

NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1

NEEDED               libc.so.6

My question is how to check/detect type 'b' library dependency ? Please suggest is there any way to detect before execution ?

Thanks in advance

Thiru

Comment: As that's purely dynamic (in theory, the user could enter the dll name at runtime), I don't see how a static check can cover this.

Comment: usually I use `ldd` command on the executable file. This produces a list of the linked objects. But I found, when deploying Qt binaries, that it does not find the plugins. I am wandering if that is because they-themselves are linked from the linked qt libraries (i.e. second order linking)...

Comment: well, plugins aren’t linked, they are loaded at runtime. ldd or other tools don’t know which plugins will be needed at runtime. Also some are optional and loaded on demand (SQL or image format plugins, for example), others are not (platform plugin), others might never be loaded. You’ll have to make a conscious decision which plugins you need and deploy those accordingly. Or just package/deploy all of them. And then the plugins themselves also have dependencies, but those are usually linked and can be identified by running ldd on the plugin .so files.

Comment: Since it's dynamically loaded, you can't check before runtime. You can, however, load the library (see [`QLibrary`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlibrary.html)) during initialization and terminate if it fails to load.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such use full information

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestion and support

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to generally check for libraries that are loaded dynamically and whose functions are called via function pointers.

In some special cases, as a hack, you can attempt various ways of reverse-engineering the executable, e.g. statically analyzing code around the calls to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` on Windows. You could derive some heuristics that would work on many executables, but there's no way that's guaranteed to work, other than executing the code in a virtual machine and intercepting all calls to `LoadLibrary`/`dlopen` as they happen.

Comment: He's on Linux, not Windows. :-)

Comment: It doesn't matter what the platform is: trying to figure out what `dlopen` will be called with is equivalent to solving the halting problem. You can guess and you can solve certain very narrow cases without running the code, but other than that you can't but run the code to see what it does.